# Android: sorting letters in EditText

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, collections

[Here is a screenshot of my output][1]

I am trying to sort the elements of an array.
I have stored the elements to the array from EditText1(ed) and I want to sort them and display them in EditText2.
I am done with storing them and displaying them, i wanted to sort them using `Collections.sort(array);` but it shows me that there is something wrong.

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
 EditText ed,ed2;
RelativeLayout container;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     ed= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);


    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            allEds.add(ed);
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];
            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
                Log.e("My data", strings[i]);
                ed2.setText(strings[i]);

            }


        }
    });
```

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dowdE.jpg

Comment: You say that something is wrong, could you show the error message or whatever is wrong

Comment: it show red line under the array name. i tried to type it in different places but still didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to sort Strings in an EditText or an actual EditText object?

Comment: Could you show an example output of your Log?

Comment: I edited my question and add a screenshot.

Comment: So, you want to sort the numbers in the first edittext and display them in the other one?

Comment: First EditText "store" letters to array, second EditText Sould diplay "sorted"  letters .

Comment: Are they always numbers, always text or a combination of the two

Comment: Might be numbers or letters but not combination of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will probably work (replace the code in the onClick with this):

```
String[] strings = ed.getText().toString().split("\\r?\\n");
Arrays.sort(strings);
String output = TextUtils.join("\\n",strings);
ed2.setText(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

may be something like this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> allEds = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText ed,ed2;
    RelativeLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ed= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
      ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      final Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
      container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);

      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        String str = ed.getText().toString();
        String lines[] = str.split("\\r?\\n");
        Arrays.sort(lines);

        ed2.setText(TextUtils.join("\n", lines));
    }
});
```